# How to access an ArrayList of another class without generating a new instance every time?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, instance

What I want to do is have a separate class, lets say `MyArrayListClass` which contains an ArrayList. `Class1` would add a String to the list and `Class2` would retrieve the list.

The way I am currently doing things, every time a button is pressed, I create a new Instance of MyArrayClass and add an element to the arraylist, like so: `MyArrayClass.newInstance.addToList("example string");` The list is retrived by calling `UserHexData.newInstance().getList();`

When I create a  new Instance of MyArrayListClass, the values previously in the list are now gone. Calling MyArrayListClass is going to return null, as creating a new instance, creates a new ArrayList.

```
 public class MyArrayListClass {
//The class containing my ArrayList business logic

            private List<String> list;

    public static MyArrayListClass newInstance() {

        return new MyArrayListClass ();
    }

    public MyArrayListClass (){

        list = new ArrayList<>();

    }

public void addToList(String hex) {
        list.add("Some Sting" );
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

Is there a way to access an ArrayList of another class without generating a new instance every time?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just keep a reference to the class with the array list? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve by using that newInstance() method (which is exactly what is wiping out all elements you've previously added). Is there a reason why you'd want a new MyArrayList class on each button press?

Comment: Another class should never have access to a list. Instead you should iterate through the list and then return the string inside the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a Singleton pattern for this.

see: 
[click me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)